# Does the sum of sequence of measurable functions converge outside a set of measure zero?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of measurable functions defined on a probability space, such that:

$$P(f_n = 1/n) = 1 - P(f_n = 0) = 1/(n^2)$$

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{f_n}$ converge outside a set of measure zero?

The hint is to use one of the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, but I'm confused what $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{f_n}$ even means. The infinite sum of functions is supposed to mean what? Can someone make sense of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you substitute $f_n =\frac{1}{n}$ in the summation and see what happens?

Comment: @jay-sun Is this supposed to help the OP to find the proof?

Comment: @Did It's an indirect pointer to apply the basic definition of the Borel-Cantelli lemma which I think the OP is missing out here.

Comment: @jay-sun clearly the infinite sum of 1/(n^2) converges, but how can I apply the borel-cantelli lemma to the sum of a sequence of functions?

Comment: @tyur43 take a look here in wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A_n:=\{x,f_n(x)=\frac 1n\}$. What about the convergence of the series of measures of the $A_n$? Why does Borel-Cantelli's lemma help up to conclude?

Comment: I just had a realization that $\sum{fn}$ probably refers to the sum of the supremum values of {$f_n$}.

Since $P(f_n = 1/n) = 1 - P(f_n = 0)$, that means that outside a set of measure zero, $f_n$ only takes on values $1/n$ or 0, for each n. Then, letting An be as you said, the fact that the sum of the probabilities (the sum of 1/(n^2)) converges means that P(limsup An) = 0, which means that almost surely there are not infinitely many fn's that take on value 1/n. Thus the rest are zero, so the sum will be finite, thus sum of fn's does converge outside set of measuer zero.