# Does a sum of measurable functions converge outside a set of measure zero?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on a probability space, such that
$$
P\left(f_n=\frac1n\right)=1-P(f_n=0)=\frac1n.
$$
Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converge outside a set of measure zero?

A similar problem was solved here: [Does the sum of sequence of measurable functions converge outside a set of measure zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316275/does-the-sum-of-sequence-of-measurable-functions-converge-outside-a-set-of-measu). The only difference  is that in my problem $P(f_n=1/n)$ and $P(f_n=0)$ are not summable, so the Borel-Cantelli lemma does not apply. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ef_n=\frac  1n P(f_n=\frac  1n)+0P(f_n=0)=\frac  1{n^{2}}$. Hence $\sum Ef_n=\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\infty$. By Tonelli's Theorem this implies $E \sum f_n <\infty$. In turn this implies $\sum f_n <\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be the probability space.
$$
\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\omega)\,d\mu(\omega)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int f_n(\omega)\,d\mu(\omega)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty
$$
Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\omega)$ is integrable, so
$$
\mu\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\omega) < \infty\right\} = 1 .
$$

Comment: I don't quite follow. For example, $f_n$ is not defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Made a notational change.